# How are iPhone and Android applications developed?

Tags: iphone, android

I would like to know:

1. What frameworks are available
2. Which language is useful for Android /iPhone apps (.NET ,JAVA,C++)

Answer (score 1):

Android development is in Java. See [this link](http://developer.android.com/resources/index.html) for useful resources. You can also look around that site to find out how to install the SDK and all that stuff.

I don't know much about iPhone development, but I know it uses Objective-C for coding and that you have to be on a Mac to be able to develop for it. I'm sure some other people are going to be able to share some links that will point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

iPhone Apps are developed in Xcode, which will only run on Apple Machines. Apps are coded in Objective c. You need to join the Mac iOS developer program to sell through the Apple store: 
http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/